# SwiftUI PreviewProvider - Updating took more than 5 seconds

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to preview my SwiftUI app in the canvas, however whenever trying to create dummy data for the `ObservedObject` I get the following error

> Updating took more than 5 seconds (99499)

If I remove the `ObservedObject` it builds fine. Does anybody have any suggestions.

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject var model: Model

  var body: some View {
        
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            
           Text("Theres literally nothing here")
            
        }// End of scroll view
        .navigationBarTitle("Show me something")
        
    }// End of navigation view
  }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {

    let profile = Profile(uid: "rtdfgbrtsdgf", email: "test@testing.com", location: GeoPoint(latitude: 34563456.765654, longitude: 758675.56765))

    let model: = ViewModel(profile: profile)
    
    ContentView(model:model)

  }
}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

   private let firestoreManager = FirestoreManager()

   private var db = Firestore.firestore()
   var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

   @Published var profile: Profile {didSet{didChange.send() }}

   init(profile: Profile) {
      self.profile = profile
   }
}
```

Comment: Works fine after fixed compiler errors. Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

Comment: @Asperi interesting, I am wondering if it is something to do with importing Firebase for GeoPoint. I am running 12.2 / iOS 14. (Runs fine on device)

Comment: Not sure why, but is was the GeoPoint property, making it an optional and giving it a nil value for the test data solved the problem; this required me to do a lot of refactoring